# Match a text object by its position in Acrobat Pro's preflight

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

When I go through the *Preflight: Edit Check* window, I cannot find the criteria that could match property "Position". Is it possible to do it?

[image: match the Position(pt)]

What I'm trying to do is to remove some text in a book (pdf format) by using the Preflight -function in Acrobat Pro DC.

First, I open the Preflight window and do a PDF analysis which will list all objects of the whole book or within a certain page range. In the picture up above, I specified only one page, which is page 53. The picture shows the analysis result.

I'm trying to create a New Check to match the text in Position 63.0/483.408 and then do a fixup, that will remove the matched text. The problem is I can't find the criteria matching this position property, see the picture below.

[image]

There is a lot of properties to choose from, but nothing related to position. There is no result if I type *position* in the search box.

The most relative one I found is this one, but I still cannot manage to match the text via it.
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's actually a property you can use for the purpose. You're looking at Font properties, so could you maybe replace the screenshot with the one where Font is chosen in the Group-window? That shows what properties are actually available on the level you're now working on.

Comment: Thought so... you just need to choose an available property or an alternative one. Your question sort of implies that the same text in same position is in every page. If so, I'd try with something in Text group.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yeah, you're right! I want to remove text appearing in every page. The *Text positioning operators (%)* seems to accept only percentage value.  I don't know if I can convert the *63.0/483.408* thing into a percent value.

Comment: Yap, frustrating... well the values are in points, so if you can find the page dimensions in points percentage's doable... I _think_ that's what it refers to. Sorry been a very long time since I've preflighted.